# Dynamic pathFor on Meteor/Iron Router

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I'm new to Meteor and I'm trying to create a dynamic value for `pathFor`. For example, let's say I have the following routes:

- `brands.list`: it lists all laptops brands (E.g. `Apple`, `Acer`, etc.);
- `brands.single`: it lists all laptops from `x` brand (e.g. `Macbook Pro`, `Macbook Air`, etc.);
- `product.single`: it displays the selected product.

I'd like to use the same `list` template to list all laptops `brands` and `products`:

```
{{#each lists}}
  <li><a href="{{pathFor route=listUrl}}">{{title}}</a></li>
{{/each}}
```

At first, I thought I could pass a `listUrl` value and set it to the right path inside the data context, like this:

```
this.layout('AppLayout', {
  data: {
    listUrl: 'product.single',
    lists: Products.find({brand: this.params.slug})
  }
});
```

This way, I could pass `listUrl` as `brands.single` in the `brands.list` route or as `product.single` in the `brands.single` one.

However, it doesn't work. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `{{#each lists}}` the `listUrl` value is then trying to be found in context of each item of `lists`. 
So you can either put the `listUrl` variable inside each item in lists, or access parent context like this:

```
{{#each lists}}
  <li><a href="{{pathFor route=../listUrl}}">{{title}}</a></li>
{{/each}}
```